# ListView does not update at once

Tags: android

I am making a "Note" program to practice and learn - my first "freestyle" project after reading a book on the subject. The way i figured i would do this is to store the title and content of the note in a SQLite table, and insert and remove from the table as needed.

The first activity consists of a ListView which gets all the notes(rows) from the DB. The user is supposed to press a button at the first activity, which says "New note", which then leads to another activity where you can enter the title and the content of the note, press the "Save" button, and then with an intent, return to the activity with the ListView where the newly added note plus all earlier created notes are displayed in the ListView.

My problem is that when the intent starts the activity with the ListView from the NewNote activity, the newly added note wont show in the ListView at once. If i then add a new note again, it returns to the first activity, but then the note i added first is displayed. And so it goes on. In other words the list on the first activity is always "one note behind", as it only adds the note i added the last time and not the one i recently added. Maybe its a bad explanation, but i think thats as clear as it gets. I spent alot of time today logging and trying to find the problem but i cant seem to figure this out on my own.

Here is my code.

Starting with my database class:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DB";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLE_NOTES = "Notes";
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
private static final String KEY_CONTENT = "content";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_PERSON_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NOTES + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT," + KEY_CONTENT + " INTEGER" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_PERSON_TABLE);
}

public void dropTable() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NOTES);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NOTES);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void newNote(String title, String content) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    values.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
    db.insert(TABLE_NOTES, null, values);

    db.close();
}

public void deleteNote(String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NOTES, KEY_ID + "=" + id, null);
}

public ArrayList<Note> getNotes() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<Note> notes = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NOTES, new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_CONTENT}, null, null, null, null, KEY_ID + " DESC", null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Note note = new Note(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
        notes.add(note);
    }

    db.close();
    return notes;
}

public void deleteAll() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("delete from " + TABLE_NOTES);
    db.close();
   }
}
```

My Main activity, ListActivity:

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DatabaseHandler dbh;
    private ListView list;
    private ArrayAdapter<Note> listAdapter;
    private Button newBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    dbh = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String id = intent.getStringExtra("Id");
    String title = intent.getStringExtra("Title");
    String content = intent.getStringExtra("Content");

    //If save button is pressed at NewNote
    if (title != null && content != null) {
        dbh.newNote(title, content);
        Log.d("note", title + " added");
    }

    //If delete button is pressed at NewNote
    if (id != null) {
        dbh.deleteNote(id);
    }

    initWidgets();

    }


public void initWidgets() {
    list = findViewById(R.id.list);
    newBtn = findViewById(R.id.newButton);

    newBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent newButtonIntent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, NewNote.class);
            startActivity(newButtonIntent);
        }
    });

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Note note = listAdapter.getItem(i);
            Intent editIntent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, EditNote.class);
            editIntent.putExtra("Title", note.getTitle());
            editIntent.putExtra("Content", note.getContent());
            editIntent.putExtra("Id", note.getId());
            startActivity(editIntent);

        }
    });

    refreshList();

}

public void refreshList() {
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, dbh.getNotes());
    list.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    Log.d("note", "View updated");
}
}
```

My NewNote class:

```
public class NewNote extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText title;
    private EditText content;
    private Button btnSave;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_note);
    initWidgets();
}

public void initWidgets() {
    title = findViewById(R.id.title);
    content = findViewById(R.id.content);
    btnSave = findViewById(R.id.saveButton);


    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(NewNote.this, ListActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("Title", title.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("Content", content.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(i);
        }
    });


}
}
```

Not really relevant as i have not implemented it fully, if you are just reading through the code you can 100% just ignore this class - my EditNote class:

```
public class EditNote extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText title;
    private EditText content;
    private Button saveBtn;
    private Button deleteBtn;
    private String noteId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_note);

    initWidgets();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    title.setText(intent.getStringExtra("Title"));
    content.setText(intent.getStringExtra("Content"));
    noteId = intent.getStringExtra("Id");
}

public void initWidgets() {
    title = findViewById(R.id.titleEdit);
    content = findViewById(R.id.contentEdit);
    deleteBtn = findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);

    deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(EditNote.this, ListActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("Id", noteId);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Also there are my XML files, and a Note class which only consists of member variables and setters/getters, either of them i consider relevant. I think the problem is somewhere in the DB class, ListActivity class, or NewNote class.

Maybe this is alot to read for you and maybe its messy or im doing something wrong with the posting but i would be grateful for help on how to resolve this issue. Also if you see other things i can do better please point them out!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked that your ListActivity is going through onCreate() when (re-)started from the NewNoteActivity?
My suspicion is that it is only resumed, not created, thus not refreshing the list.

Comment: I have checked that, in the code over i am logging  Log.d("note", title + " added") at onCreate(), and it prints every time, with the title of the current note im trying to add. Also if it never went to onCreate() nothing would ever be added to the list, which it does, just not before i have added another note to the list. Really weird. But thanks though, good try!

Comment: Have you checked that the adapter is created with the right data (incl. the new note)?
Try to narrow down if it's a problem with the data itself or just the ListView not displaying it properly.

Comment: I am also newbie, but I think you need to override onResume in mainactivity and call refreshList(); –

Comment: Ok thanks FWeigl, that took me a step further, im logging all the data now and it doesen't update the adapter with the newly added note. I update the adapter with an arraylist returned from my db class containing all the rows in the table, so im starting to get sure the problem is somewhere in either newNote() or getNotes() in my Db class.